# Calculated column Update daily

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a column that calculates the days until expiration for certifications. To do so I use the Today function:

```
=[Certification Expiration Date]-TODAY()
```

I have noticed that this type of column doesn't automatically update daily, is there a way to do so it feeds into my Power BI Dashboard correctly.

Online I have seen that a flow can be created using "Send HTTP Data to SharePoint" but for some reason it is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this once:

```
=[Certification Expiration Date]-NOW()
```

Also, This is a known behavior of calculated columns that calculated column values are calculated only when:

- A new item is created
- An existing item is updated
- Calculated column formula is updated

Check more information in my answer given on this thread: [Impact on Performance of Calculated Columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/290757/impact-on-performance-of-calculated-columns/290774#290774)

Comment: Is there a way to use a Flow to update the formula every day? Thats the question I was asking.

Comment: You can run scheduled flow daily and update the calculated column definition/formula via flow. But I am not sure if values for all items will be updated or not when column formula is updated via flow. Try this: https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/set-calculated-field-formula-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api. Let me know if it works for you.